# Calling different JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry, if this is a stupid question, I'm new to JavaScript. I'm trying to create links which will automatically update according to the page you're on. It worked fine when I just had one of them, but apparently, the first link also gives me the same output as the first one. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- QR API generator call -->
  <script>
    baseurl="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data="
    function buildQR(item)
    {
        item.href=baseurl+window.location.href;
        return true;
    }
    </script>
  <!-- Sharing append link via JavaScript -->
  <script>
  baseurl="whatsapp://send?text="
  function buildURL(item)
  {
      item.href=baseurl+window.location.href;
      return true;
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<a onclick="return buildQR(this)" href="">Generate QR</a>
<a onclick="return buildURL(this)" href="" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share on WhatsApp</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for helping me out.

**P.S.** I'm trying to achieve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34145738/7947125), but with two links this time.

Comment: Can you give some examples of the desired output? For now, I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: if you're new to javascript, it's worth reading through a few _modern_ tutorials, because the code you're showing might have been okay a decade ago, but is kind of bad as modern HTML/JS. Don't use inline js like `onclick`, get your elements and then `addEventListener` whatever it needs - also, unless it's a true link, don't use `<a>`, use `<button>` because that's what it is, and then use CSS to style that however it needs to look. Also, say what kind of variable you're using. `var`? `let`? `const`? etc.

Comment: @CalvinNunes When someone clicks on the link to Generate QR, it should append the URL of the page the user's on to "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=". Similarly, when someone clicks on the link to Share on WhatsApp, it should do it for "whatsapp://send?text="

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans is it because I'm using <a> to call JavaScript? Because I've heard it's frowned upon.

Comment: It's because of so many things. You also don't have a `<!doctype html>` at the top to indicate this is true HTML5, you're missing a charset meta and a title, all that JS should be in its own file so you can load it with `<script src="..." defer></script>`, etc. -- it just looks like the kind of HTML/JS that highly outdated tutorials/books would teach you to use.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34145408/insert-current-url-into-a-link-using-js-and-html, only with two links this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the scope of the `baseurl` variable. It's being declared as a global variable, which means in your first script tag it gets set with the initial value, then in the second script tag it gets set to a new value. Both of those scripts are executed when the page loads, so it's pretty much immediately setting `baseurl` equal to the second value.

I would recommend reading more about variable scoping (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) and closures (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to better understand the issue.

To fix it, you can either use a different variable name for the second instance of `baseurl` (something like `baseurl1`, maybe), or move the variable declarations inside the function declarations to wrap them inside those closures.

Something like this should work:

```html
<!-- QR API generator call -->
<script>    
    function buildQR(item) {
        var baseurl="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=";

        item.href=baseurl+window.location.href;
        return true;
    }
</script>
<!-- Sharing append link via JavaScript -->
<script>
    function buildURL(item) {
        var baseurl="whatsapp://send?text=";

        item.href=baseurl+window.location.href;
        return true;
    }
</script>
```